# Decyphering a simple regex

Tags: regex

The regular expression in question is

```
(\d{3,4}[.-]?)+
```

sample text

```
707-7019-789
```

My progress so far

```
(            )+  a capturing group, capturing one or more
 \d{3,4}         digit, in quantities 3 or 4
        [.-]?    dot (or something) or hyphen, in quantities zero or one <-- this is the part I'm interested in
```

From my understanding this should match 3 or 4 digit number, followed by a dot (or anything, since dot matches anything) or a hyphen, bundled in a group, one or more times. Why doesn't this matches a

```
707+123-4567
```

then?

Comment: `.` matches anything outside of `[]` - inside of `[]`, it's just a dot.

Comment: when you use . in [] it will match only dot. The [] remove the special meaning of. So in you you case you will match only 3 or 4 digits followed by . or - or empty string and this group should repeat one or more times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` in a character group `[]` is just a literal `.`, it does not have the special meaning "anything". `[.-]?` means "a dot or a hyphen or nothing", because the entire group is made optional with the `?`.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Other".

Answer (score 1):

The brackets remove the functionality of the dot. 
Brackets mean "Range"/"Character class".
Thus you are saying Choose from the list/range/character class .- 
You aren't saying choose from the list "anything"- (anything is the regular meaning of .)

Comment: I see now. Maybe better rephrase that "range" to "from the set of [.-] so it's either one or the other".

Answer (score 1):

```
[.-]?
```

What this means literally:

#### character class `[.-]`

- Match *only one* out of the following characters: `.` and `-` literally.

#### lazy quantifier `?`

- Repeat the last token between 0 and 1 times, *as few times as possible*.