# Regex to match a period

Tags: regex, matching

I am trying to figure out a regular expression that matches a . (period).
I looked for a formula but there was no formula that matches period.

```
12903,03930.
```

Comment: This is addressed in the [StackOverflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) under "Other", about 1/2 to 2/3 down. Relevant answers: [What special characters must be escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/399078), [`[.]`:literal dot character](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21929764)

Comment: Thank you, I will check them out.

Answer (score 31):

You just need to escape the . as it's normally a [meta character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). The escape character is a backslash:

```
\.
```

E.g:

```
/[0-9]+\./
```

Will match a number followed by a period.

If you wanted to match the entire number except the period, you could do this:

```
/([0-9,]+)/
```

Here we use the range operator to select all numbers or a comma, 1 or more times.

Comment: I see. How about everything(including comma) but without period?

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate matching everything but the period

Comment: Thank you for editing and explanation. if I want to match only the end of digit, it should be /([0-9$]+)/ ? and first /([0-9^]+)/?

Comment: Nope, it would be `/^[0-9]/` for the first digit, and `/[0-9]$/` for the last digit. The ^ and $ operators do different things when inside the range operator (`[]`)

Comment: () and [] confuses me. I want to check that theses are Regex for JavaScript Python, and grep?