# using regex with a variable to search a sentence

Tags: javascript

I am using the following regex to seach a sentence and want to match only values that are followed by a period.  I am confused to why the following regex is true since the ta isnt followed by a period.  How would I change it so doesnt match?

```
let text = 'Paracetamol takes up to an hour to work. to '

let regex = new RegExp("ta" + ".", "i")
console.log(regex.test(text))
```

Comment: In a regex some characters have special meanings.  The period is one of them; it means match any character.  Try escaping it with a backslash:  \.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to match a period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951369/regex-to-match-a-period)

Comment: I changed it to this and it still isnt working,. ```let text = 'Paracetamol takes up to an hour to work. to '

let regex = new RegExp("ta" + "\.", "i")
console.log(regex.test(text))```

Comment: You escaped the period for the string, but not the regex, you'll have to write your regex with a literal, or escape the backslash with another backslash

Comment: As Seblor said, this should do the thing: `let regex = new RegExp("ta"+"\\.", "i");`

Comment: Ok thanks I forgot I needed two backslashs when using the regex constructor