# Why `.` in PEP 0263 regex?

Tags: python, regex, syntax, pep

In [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) the format for defining the encoding of a Python file is defined as:

```
coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)
```

Why is there a `.` in the regex, or alternatively, why is there `-` and `\w`? So far as I understand, the `.` matches any character except a newline, so either `[-\w]` or `[.]` would match the legal names, which consist of **alphanumeric characters and the dash**.

**What is the reason for having both `-\w` and `.` specified together in `[-\w.]`?**

Comment: `.` is [not a special character in a character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Check [the reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean), there's a link to [`[.]:literal dot character`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21929764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `.` and `-` in character classes, they both behave differently. In character classes, `.` has no special meaning and will be treated as dot only, where as `-` can be used to specify ranges like `a-zA-Z0-9`.

Since we don't use `-` to represent a range in this case, both `.` and `-` will be matching themselves only. They will not have special meanings.

Also note that, `\w` can be defined as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. It matches only underscore character (`_`) not the dash (`-`).

Quoting from the [Python RegEx documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax),

> #### \w
>
> When the `LOCALE` and `UNICODE` flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. With `LOCALE`, it will match the set `[0-9_]` plus whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[0-9_]` plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that `.` matches only the literal `.` in this context.