# PCRE Pattern match to URL

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to configure a website plugin and need to set a PCRE url pattern for certain pages on my site.

I exclude certain pages using the following patterns successfully.

```
^/wp-admin/
^/wp-login.php
^/content/
```

However I also need to exclude pages which are in the following patterns

```
www.site.com/post_id/post_name/feed/
e.g. www.site.com/345345/myawesomepost/feed/
```

Where the only static component of the url is /feed/  Would anyone know how to do this using PCRE expressions..?

Comment: does your regexes really exclude pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude urls like this

```
Format:  www.site.com/post_id/post_name/feed/
Example: www.site.com/345345/myawesomepost/feed/
```

you might consider the following regular expression:

```
^(?:\w+\.)+\w+/[0-9]+/\w+/feed/$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QreaDoU3izbQ)

Free-spaced:

- `^`: [Start-of-line anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/578411)
- `(?:`: [Non-capturing group] of
- `\w+\.`: One-or-more [word-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874899), followed by a literal dot (which could also be written as [`[.]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21929764)
- `)+`: [One-or-more times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399)
- `\w+/`: One-or-more word characters followed by a (literal) slash
- `[0-9]+/`: One-or-more [digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9), followed by a slash
- `\w+/`
- `feed/`: The word "feed" followed by a slash.
- `$`: [End-of-line anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/578411)

Here is an more general and comprehensive answer on [using regex to match urls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496), that may also be of interest.

---

(All the above links come from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Common Tasks > Validation > Internet". Please consider bookmarking the FAQ for future reference.)

Answer (score 0):

Domething like this should match

`^/.+/feed/`

It just matches every url that ends with /feed/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use:

```
/www.+\/feed\//gi
```

will match:

```
www.site.com/post_id/post_name/feed/
www.site.com/345345/myawesomepost/feed/
```

If the urls contain 'http://', you should alter the pattern to:

```
/http.+\/feed\//gi
```

The 'i' at the end can be left out if you are sure 'feed' will never contain capital letters.