# What does float range inside square braces "[ ]" in regex mean?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to understand what this regex(`[0.00-9.00]+`) in python does. The way I understand this is it would match any of `0 . 0 0-9 . 0 0`, so the zeroes are redundant here. Since there is a `.` inside it should match any character and the complete match should be a non-empty sequence of characters not necessarily digits, but it doesn't behave that way. Am I missing anything?

[Few examples of how it behaves](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5B0.00-9.00%5D%2B&test_string=42uint42.243%0A000.01301%0A1765....824&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: No, `.` in a character range does not match 'any' character, only a literal dot.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BSZI6b/1

Comment: Also, see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976018/does-a-dot-have-to-be-escaped-in-a-character-class-square-brackets-of-a-regula and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929693/decyphering-a-simple-regex/21929764#21929764

Answer (score 6):

The zeroes are indeed redundant. The `.` only matches a literal `.` because it is part of a *character class*, the `[...]` syntax. It has no special meaning there.

So the character class could be reduced to:

```
[0-9.]+
```

and still match the exact same inputs.

The author of that regex text seems to have confused the `-` feature in a character class with a numeric range feature; there is no such thing in a regex. You'd have to match individual characters that in aggregate can be read as real numbers. The following would actually match such numbers:

```
(?<!\d)\d\.\d\d(?!\d)
```

where the negative look-behind and look-ahead make sure there are not *more* digits surrounding this text. `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]` here.

See [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/YItoNX/1).

Comment: That explains it. Thanks for the answer!